# Bind combobox elements to data source

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, combobox, textblock

I have a combobox which hosts a textblock child element. I want to bind the textblock inside the combobox to a property called ResultList. I tried the code below, but it doesn't work. What have I missed out?

```
    <ComboBox x:Name="Test" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="79,42,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="344" 
              IsEditable="True">
        <ComboBox.Resources>
            <system:Double x:Key="{x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey}">0</system:Double>
        </ComboBox.Resources>
        <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}" >
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFFFFF"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
            </Style>
        </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ResultList, Mode=OneWay}" DataContext="{Binding Path=ResultList, Mode=OneWay}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ComboBox>
```

Comment: where is the `ItemsSource` in you `comboBox` ? I guess you will like to bind `ResultList` to `ItemsSource` instead.

Comment: What object has the `ResultList` property? How is the `DataContext` and/or `ItemsSource` set on the `ComboBox`?

Comment: Yes I can bind to ItemSource, and that works, but how do I then bind this my textblock?

Comment: I assume by its name that `ResultList` is a list of items, so binding it to a text block doesn't make much sense. 
If what you are trying to do is display each of the items in the comboBox then like other have pointed out you should bind the `ItemsSource` of your `ComboBox`. In Addition, If you are simply just presenting it as plain text, comboBox does it for you and there is no need to use `DataTemplate` ...

Comment: @Prof, do you mean when bind `ItemsSource` to your `comboBox` you don't know what for the `textblock` to bind with? just use `<TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>`

Comment: Yes, I ResultList is a list of items, so I need to bind my combobox itemsource to ResultList, then bind my Textblock to the comboboxes's ItemSource. I tried
 <TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemsSource, Mode=OneWay}" DataContext="{Binding Test}" />

But that didn't work. Please explain why?

Comment: Woo <TextBlock FontSize="10" Text="{Binding}"  /> worked

Comment: Correct, that is what I mean...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, to sum all the comments up:

You need to bind the list to `ItemsSource` of `comboBox`.

```
<ComboBox x:Name="Test" ItemsSrouce="{Binding ResultList}" ....>
```

And set `TextBlock` in the `ItemTemplate` to something like:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Age}" ..../> 
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" ..../>
```

Comment: Yup I actually just worked it out how to do the fields. You don't even need to specify path

Comment: @Prof, Correct, Just personal pereference, that I like to use `Path` in ItemTemplate

Comment: easy peasy. I am impressed this took only about 25 mins to solve. That everyone

Answer (score 0):

You can't set both the `DataContext` *and* the `Text` property to the same value:

```
"{Binding Path=ResultList, Mode=OneWay}"
```

You can try this:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding, Mode=OneWay}" DataContext="{Binding Path=ResultList}" />
```

But this might be better:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ResultList, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

Of course, it is hard to answer when you haven't provided all of the necessary information, such as what has been asked in the comments.