# Bind two Combox

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, binding, combobox

There is two combobox in my WPF app.

```
<ComboBox x:Name="itemsList" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,90.767,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="215" IsEditable="True" Height="23"/>


<ComboBox x:Name="pSize" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="230,90.767,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="109.538" Height="23" IsEditable="True" />
```

First combobox fetch items from database with this function which i initialize when app loads

```
  void getAllItems()
    {
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT  DISTINCT item_name FROM items", conn);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (dr.Read())
        {
            String items = dr.GetString(0);
            itemsList.Items.Add(items);
        }


        conn.Close();
    }
```

I want to bind my second combobox "pSize" with "itemlist". I want to get the value from itemlist and pass to the method which generate items for "pSize" from database according to the parameters.I tried to bind it but not working.

Comment: Are you asking for some event when itemsList selectedItem changes?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use WPF, then you should use it properly and *not* like WinForms like you are currently doing. In WPF, we don't programmatically add items to UI controls. Instead we add items to a collection and then data bind that to the UI controls. In this way, we can data bind the same collection to as many UI controls as we like. So, try something like this:

```
private ObservableCollection<string> items = new ObservableCollection<string>();
public ObservableCollection<string> Items
{
    get { return items; }
    set { items = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("Items"); }
}
```

...

```
void getAllItems()
{
    conn.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT  DISTINCT item_name FROM items", conn);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    while (dr.Read())
    {
        String items = dr.GetString(0);
        Items.Add(items);
    }
    conn.Close();
}
```

...

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" />
```

Don't forget to set the `DataContext` of the `UserControl` or `Window` to an instance of the class where the `Item` property is declared and populated. You would probably also benefit from reading the [Data Binding Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN.

Comment: With this method i have to change many thing in my application, can u tell easy approach like i told u in my question. I just want to pass parameter to a method when itemList change.

Comment: *With this method i have to change many thing in my application*... that's the point! If you don't want to program correctly, then you'll have to ask someone else. I will only show you how to program the proper WPF way.

Answer (score 0):

You'd better create a model, and apply it to each Combobox. Now you can code you bussiness logic to generate pSize items in this model using data from database.

You can also use LINQ to apply some method to each List element and bind result (List) with you pSize.

```
List<T> newList = items.ForEach(item=> someMethod(item));
```

where T is string, in your case (as I see).

Also look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18825100/bind-combobox-elements-to-data-source?rq=1) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17011196/filling-and-binding-two-combobox-wpf-caliburn-micro?rq=1) threads.

Comment: I want to bind pSize to itemsList, and get the value of itemsList and pass it to a method. So that method generate items for pSize. I just wanna know how to bind pSize with method which gets value of itemsList

Comment: its a one way binding, itemsList is not binded

Comment: @BurhanakaSLIMSHADY , then use LINQ approach.

Comment: look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17011196/filling-and-binding-two-combobox-wpf-caliburn-micro?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way, no need to make a list. I found it my self:

```
private void itemsList_DropDownClosed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   MessageBox.Show(itemsList.Text) 
}
```